# Recently exposed pipe seems to go nowhere in lawn

Tags: plumbing, old-pipes

Just noticed this pipe in my front lawn. Must have been recently exposed, possibly by the landscapers. Pipe is open and not clogged. Seems to have been buried and not go anywhere? Any idea what it is?

[image]

Comment: do you have smoke bombs? That can find the other end, but I suspect it connects to your gutter's downspouts.

Comment: In some areas this is a way to drain the run off it fills that area and goes over the curb. Cutting the curb may not be allowed and even end up with large fines but allowing the water to flow over the curb was legal.

Answer (score 2):

It's a drain. What, exactly, it's draining is not obvious from the limited view of the picture, but it's carrying water from some higher point to this point, where it can (as Ed Beal notes) flow over the curb and into the street.

Grab an umbrella (and possibly a flashlight) and revisit it in or soon after a rain storm.

It may simply be removing excess water from part of the yard, or it may serve other purposes. But it's definitely a drain.

Comment: Thank you. It probably does connect to the downspout. I'm debating whether it needs to be covered up again or not.

Comment: It probably should _not_ be covered, @erg0s4m. It will drain better this way.